In Windows Event log what is the provider name for OpenSSH
I want to read OpenSSH Event logs from C++ code.
This is what I use to open the log:
  hEventLog = OpenEventLog(NULL, provider_name);

I tried this with "PowerShell" as the provider_name, and successfully read the PowerShell logs from the hEventLog.
When I try this with "OpenSSH" I do not get the OpenSSH logs when reading from the handle.
What value of provider_name will open the log that I need?
Some context:
My endgame is to get notified in my program on new SSH connections to the machine.
I see that there are connection logs in the OpenSSH EventLog. I want to listen on the OpenSSH EventLog and get notified for every log there, to identify new connections.

The post
Availability Anywhere Part 19 — Banning RDP and SSH attacks
incidentally lists the contents of an OpenSSH event:
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="OpenSSH" Guid="{C4B57D35-0636-4BC3-A262-370F249F9802}" /> 

To answer the question : The Provider Name is "OpenSSH", as you tried.
As to why your C++ code fails, coding questions are more the domain of
Stack Overflow.
The only remark I can make is that these events are created by the
OpenSSH server, not by the client (in case that helps).

My problem isn't solved, but you have answered the question. I guess the Provider Name isn't the cause of my problem.
